# Hide a div element outside the tab content just when a tab is selected and show it again when swiching tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I need to hide the "related" div on this site when the third tab is selected (Guia de Tallas), and show it again when switching the other tabs. Is this possible?

This is the site: http://tinyurl.com/d6jk4gf

Comment: What does the display space issue have to do with hiding related divs? If they are 2 separate question then keep them separate. Now it just gets confusing. You want us to help you come up with the logic to hide a relative div or look at your other issue?

Comment: Im sorry, just wanted to offer as much info as I can. But you are right. Let me edit the question, so it gets much more clear. Just want to know if is possible what I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it with the code in your javascript.js file. Add this to the end of your `$('div.htmltabs ul li a').click` function:

```
if (thisClass == "tab3") 
   $(".related").hide();
else
   $(".related").show();
```

Comment: this is working great!!! Just what I needed. Thanks very much. Also I need to do some other workarounds hidding other elements, so with this info I think Im gonna be able to solve it.